# Predicate Expression as Filter Parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a method that wraps a LINQ `Where` call (on an IQueryable) for filtering on a specific field in a collection and am at a loss for how to make it work.

For example, I have a collection of Job objects similar to the following:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}

public class StatusItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    public static readonly StatusItem Canceled = new StatusItem() { Id = (int)StatusEnum.Canceled, Name = StatusEnum.Canceled.ToString(), IsAvailable = true };
    public static readonly StatusItem Created = new StatusItem() { Id = (int)StatusEnum.Created, Name = StatusEnum.Created.ToString(), IsAvailable = true };
    public static readonly StatusItem Open = new StatusItem() { Id = (int)StatusEnum.Open, Name = StatusEnum.Open.ToString(), IsAvailable = true };
    public static readonly StatusItem Assigned = new StatusItem() { Id = (int)StatusEnum.Assigned, Name = StatusEnum.Assigned.ToString(), IsAvailable = false };
}
```

I'm hoping to have a service method that enforces filtering using only the system defined statuses, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Job> GetAll(Expression<Func<StatusItem, bool>> statusFilter)
{
    // Jobs is IQueryable<job>. How do I apply statusFilter to Job.StatusId?
    return jobs.Where(/* some magic here? */);
}
```

With a call similar to:

```
return JobService.GetAll(s => s > StatusItem.Open && s < StatusItem.Assigned);
```

**Edit:** Been staring too long at this. Brain now mush. Attempted to fix previous errors

Comment: Does it have to be an expression? Can't it be a simple Predicate<> instead?

Comment: Shouldn't `StatusId` be of type `StatusEnum`?

Comment: Can't you use [`AsQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.110).aspx) before appending the where statement?

Comment: Not sure what you really trying to do, but you are selecting StatusId from the job and attempting to return Job?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Good catch, should probably be `jobs.Where(x => statusFilter((StatusEnum)x.StatusId))`

Comment: Is `jobs` a normal in-memory list? or is it a `DbSet`?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, if the method signature could require use of StatusItem, then yes. I'm just not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: @Aaron A predicate is simply a Func that's returntype is always bool

Comment: Sorry, I guess a more accurate question would be how to tie in the use of predicate so it's applied to the Job.StatusId field?

Comment: Removed my answer as it wasn't my intention to create a pointless argument.

Comment: `s > StatusItem.Assigned && s < StatusItem.Assigned` I think this got no sense. s should be less than and greater than StatusItem.Assigned at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use `Expression<Func<Job, bool>>` instead of `Expression<Func<StatusEnum, bool>>`, which would let you write something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Job> GetAll(Expression<Func<Job, bool>> jobFilter)
{
    return jobs.Where(jobFilter);
}
```

It also has the benefit of being more flexible in case you want to filter by something other than the status.

If you really want to use `Expression<Func<StatusEnum, bool>>`, it becomes more complex, because you need to rewrite the expression to make a `Expression<Func<Job, bool>>` from the `Expression<Func<StatusEnum, bool>>`. Here's a way to do it:

```
IEnumerable<Job> GetAll(Expression<Func<StatusEnum, bool>> statusFilter)
{
    var job = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Job), "job");
    var visitor = new ParameterReplacementVisitor(
        statusFilter.Parameters[0],
        Expression.Property(job, nameof(Job.StatusId)));
    Expression<Func<Job, bool>> jobFilter =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<Job, bool>>(
            visitor.Visit(statusFilter.Body),
            job);
    return jobs.Where(jobFilter);
}

class ParameterReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;
    private readonly Expression _replacement;

    public ParameterReplacementVisitor(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression replacement)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _replacement = replacement;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == _parameter)
            return _replacement;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need, but check this:

```
jobs.Where(x => statusFilter.Compile().Invoke((StatusEnum)x.StatusId));
```

Also consider changing property StatusId to StatusEnum. Properties should also be public.

```
class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StatusEnum StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

With this kind of declaration casting to StatusEnum is not required:

```
jobs.Where(x => statusFilter.Compile().Invoke(x.StatusId));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `StatusEnum` since StatusId could also represent a user-defined status (in which case there's no corresponding enum value).

Comment: This won't work if the query is executed against a database (which is likely, otherwise the OP will be using a `Func<StatusEnum, bool>`, not an `Expression<Func<StatusEnum, bool>>`)